# iOS: performSelectorOnBackground/MainThread: does not update label

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a while statement running on the background.

```
- (IBAction)startButton
{
 [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(Counter) withObject:nil];
 .....
}

- (void) Counter 
{
  while (round) {
     if (condition)
     {
     NSString *str;
     str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counter];
     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateLabel:) withObject:str waitUntilDone:NO];      
     }
  }
}
- (void)updateLabel: (NSString*) str
 {
[self.label setText:str];
NSLog(@"I am being updated %@",str);
 }
```

The NSlog gets me the correct updated value but the label never gets updated.

What am I doing wrong?

Update:

The label is connected and after the while statement is completed it gets upated.

Also i have initialized the label.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   [super viewDidLoad];  
label.text = @"0";
}
```

Comment: I suspect self.label is nil, because your actual label is in another instance, or it's simply not connected.

Comment: Could you show how you run the while loop "in the background"? I would suspect that you're actually running this on the main thread.

Comment: check my update: I use  [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(Counter) withObject:nil];

Comment: I guess you could change waitUntilDone:NO to YES and see if your program deadlocks.

Comment: @Minthos it does not deadlock

Comment: Good, then you've narrowed down the space of possible causes significantly.

Comment: NSLog self.label at the same time that you NSLog your string.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the IBOutlet is connected in Interface Builder

**EDIT 3**

Try dispatching the request using `GCD` with `dispatch_async`, so it becomes

```
while (round) {
   if (condition)
   {
    NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counter];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
      [self updateLabel:str];
    });
   }
}
```

Another way to update a `UILabel` is to set a `NSTimer` that updates it every `x` seconds (according to you needs), instead of looping with a `while`.

That would be something like

```
NSTimer * updateLabelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)updateLabel {
  if(condition) {
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter];
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it sounds stupid but I've had the exact same problem and the exact same solution.

Comment: And that's how you decided to build your UI from code instead of using Interface Crappy Builder.

Comment: Haha no, IB has its limitations but it saves me tons of work.

Comment: The label is connected, it gets updated once the while statement is complete

Comment: I agree with @Minthos. IB allows me to draw the interface quickly, then when things gets complicated I switch to code.

Comment: If this is actually running on a background thread (which I suspect it's not), running *that thread's* runloop won't have any effect on the runloop of the main thread.

Comment: I used  [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(Counter) withObject:nil]; to run it on background thread.

Comment: @alandalusi check the answer again. Sorry for the confusion of the edits but I'm updating it as soon as you explain the problem more in details.

Comment: nothing changed, probably i should find a workaround and not use while just like you said.

Answer (score 1):

Your main thread is probably waiting for your background thread to finish. How did you start the task on the background thread?

Comment: i used [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(Counter) withObject:nil];

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dispatch_after(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self updateLabel:str];
});
```

I just prefer this over `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`.

If won't help, check if `label` isn't nil. If yes, then past more code.

EDIT AFTER FISRT COMMENT:

`NSTimer` could help, but this should work as well.

```
- (IBAction)startButton
{
    [self Counter];
}

- (void) Counter
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        while (round) {
            if (condition)
            {
                NSString *str;
                str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counter];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self updateLabel:str];
                });
            }
        }

    });

}
- (void)updateLabel: (NSString*) str
{
    [self.label setText:str];
    NSLog(@"I am being updated %@",str);
}
```

Comment: lable is not nil, and problem still exist even after using dispatch